# What is a good way to break your routes.rb file into multiple files for better management?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, partitioning

I am working on a rails 3 project with a fairly large routes file. It takes advantage of some nesting and I ran into an issue due largely to the fact that the routes files is difficult to manage.

Is there a way to break it up into multiple files?

Something like:

```
My::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints(:subdomain => 'admin') do
    include My::Application::Routes::AdminRoutes
  end

  include My::Application::Routes::MainRoutes
end
```

Or...

```
My::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints(:subdomain => 'admin') do
    require 'routes/admin_routes.rb'
  end

  require 'routes/main_routes.rb'
end
```

Or something along those lines.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`include` inserts the included module's methods into the namespace, and `require` just loads the file into the top level namespace. None of those will work for you.

Just `load` the seperate files

```
My::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints(:subdomain => 'admin') do
    load 'routes/admin_routes.rb'
  end

  load 'routes/main_routes.rb'
end
```

Comment: Looks cool to me. We're going to give it a shot and see where this takes us.

Comment: What would that 'routes/admin_routes.rb' file have to look like? We ran into some issues trying different things. Does it just need to be wrapped in a module?

Comment: As far as I know, it is evaluated right there in context, so it should just contain whatever would be in there if you had not broken it into separate files.

Answer (score 0):

another option you may use

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map| #routes.rb

  extend NewConnections

  some_method(map)  

end 


module NewConnections #/lib/new_connections.rb

  def some_method(clazz)
    clazz.root :controller => "demo"
  end

end
```

this'll connect root of your application to default controller

Comment: This would be good for Rails 2.x routing. It will still work with Rails 3.0 but using `map` is deprecated and it will fail on 3.1+